# ValueError: time data '18-Aug-08' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I try to convert the Start Date column to particular format the below output similar to '**18/August/2008**'.

> ```
>   df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
>
> 0      18-Aug-08
> 1      20-Aug-08
> 2      24-Aug-08
> 3      27-Aug-08
> 4      29-Aug-08
> 5      14-Sep-09
> 6      25-Oct-09
> 7       2-Nov-09
> ```

Comment: Pattern is wrong, use this ```"%d-%b-%y"```

Answer (score 0):

Use `%d-%b-%y` pattern, check also [`https://strftime.org/`](https://strftime.org/) for more information:

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
print (df)
  Start Date
0 2008-08-18
1 2008-08-20
2 2008-08-24
3 2008-08-27
4 2008-08-29
5 2009-09-14
6 2009-10-25
7 2009-11-02
```

If format is necesary change like `18/August/2008` then use:

```
df['Start Date'] = df['Start Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%B/%Y')
```

Comment: I followed https://strftime.org/  patterns but still i get the error                                                                                  
 ValueError: time data 'Start Date' does not match format '%d-%b-%y' (match)

Comment: @Kishan - How working `%d-%B-%y` ? If still error, what is text after `(match)` in error  ?

Comment: '18/August/2008' <---- would i be able to get output like this with some format?

Comment: getting error on your second code -->AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: @Kishan Edited answer